# Name of detect keyboard layout tool

Tags: hardware, keyboard-layout

What's the name of the program used to detect keyboards layout during ubuntu installation ? 
Is there another tool I can run after installation in other to discover the correct layout for a keyboard I bought ?

Answer (score 16):

This tool will show your current layout graphically:

```
gkbd-keyboard-display -g 1
```

This is the command used during setup for choosing your keyboard layout:

```
dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

But to make it auto-detect the keyboard, you need to change a setting in `dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration`. I'm not sure what setting, though.

To change a setting, `echo <packagename> <setting> <type> <value> | debconf-set-selections`. For example:

```
echo "keyboard-configuration console-setup/ask_detect boolean true" | debconf-set-selections
```

Hopefully this helps you.

Comment: The installation uses a graphical setup to detect the layout. `dpkg-reconfigure` is not a graphical setup.

Comment: Many upvotes, but not the answer to the question asked: a tool that autodetects a layout

Answer (score 5):

The program used to detect keyboard layout during Ubuntu installation is part of the ubuntu installer called "Ubiquity".

You can find the source code on the [Launchpad project](https://launchpad.net/ubiquity) page or download the release used in your Ubuntu version using

```
apt-get source ubiquity
```

You can navigate in the code here:
https://git.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/tree/?h=ubuntu/bionic-devel

The GTK GUI definition with the button "Detect Keyboard Layout" is here:
https://git.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/tree/gui/gtk/stepKeyboardConf.ui
Search for 'Detect Keyboard Layout', you will find 'deduce_layout'

I'm not 100% sure but I think the code that does the keyboard detection is here:
https://git.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/tree/ubiquity/plugins/ubi-console-setup.py
Search for 'deduce_layout', you will find 'calculate_keymap_button' (calculate_clicked), etc.

And here:
https://git.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/tree/ubiquity/frontend/gtk_components/keyboard_query.py
Search for 'ubiquity/text/keyboard_query_title'.

See also this webpage for easier navigation in the code: 
http://nullege.com/codes/search/ubiquity.keyboard_detector.KeyboardDetector

I hope it helps.

Comment: For future reference, the decision tree that's used for that keyboard layout tool is stored in `/usr/share/console-setup/pc105.tree`. The source is from the [debian console-setup package](https://git.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/console-setup/tree/Keyboard/pc105.tree?h=ubuntu/hirsute) and it's generated by [this script](https://git.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/console-setup/tree/Keyboard/keymaptree?h=ubuntu/hirsute).

Answer (score 0):

Install the `console-data` package.

`sudo apt-get install console-data`

Then run this command on the terminal:

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-data`

It will then allow you to change the keyboard layout.

Comment: yes, but what I want is to discover, what is my layout. I know how to change it, once I discover. The problem is that my new keyboard has some keys in non-standard places that aren't being recognized by the so.

Comment: Did you ever find out how to discover your keyboard layout?