# Auto-escape special characters (e.g. ` ~ etc.)

Tags: keyboard, special-characters

I've two computers, one (computer A) running 14.04, and another one running 16.04 (computer B).
Computer A is in french, computer B in english, both with [french keyboard layout](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/c/c4/French_pc_keyboard.svg).

On computer A, when I press <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>è</kbd> or <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>é</kbd>, it prints (e.g. on stackexchange messages) respectively `` ` `` or `~`. 
But on computer B, nothing prints when pressing same key combination. For printing backticks, I need to press  <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>è</kbd><kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>è</kbd>; and <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>é</kbd> <kbd>Space</kbd> for getting `~`. I find this rather awkward.

**Question:** How to replicate the functioning of computer A on computer B?

Comment: Do they have the same French layouts ? compare outputs of `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources` command on both computers

Comment: well, the output won't be exactly that, you have to see if it shows something like `[('xkb','fr')]` . Important part is that it shows the same text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe that you do not have the same layout on both computers ?

On computer A you can get the current layout with the command

> gkbd-keyboard-display -g 1

(the name of the layout will be in the window's title bar)
If that's not the same layout on computer B, you can run on computer B:

> sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration

and change the keyboard layout (on step 2/4) to the same as the one on computer A. Just hit `enter` on the other steps to keep current settings.

inspired of [Change keyboard layout (English UK) on command line to English US](https://askubuntu.com/questions/434849/change-keyboard-layout-english-uk-on-command-line-to-english-us)
and [Name of detect keyboard layout tool](https://askubuntu.com/questions/384758/name-of-detect-keyboard-layout-tool#455081)

Comment: Indeed: I had "french" `('xkb', 'fr')` on A, and "french (legacy, alternative)" `('xkb', 'fr+latin9')` on B. My bad. Note that the command mentioned in [Serg's comment](http://askubuntu.com/questions/825611/auto-escape-special-characters-e-g-etc?noredirect=1#comment1254962_825611) (`gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources`) makes the difference to be more obvious (since layout are, as far as I noticed, identical).