# Keyboard layout detection through questions and answers

Tags: keyboard-layout

I'm developing Ubuntu virtual machines (without desktop) destined for teaching and research. Many end up in different countries, with different keyboard layouts. By default, I prepare them with English keyboard. Some users have difficulty changing the keyboard layout from the terminal and other users are not sure what their keyboard layout is.

I'd like to have some program or script that allows the user to configure their keyboard layout by answering a series of questions, similar to the keyboard detection that appears during Ubuntu Server installation. I could not find what I was looking for. Can anyone help me find it? Does anyone have any other solutions to my problem? I need something that is very user-friendly.

Thanks a lot.

All the very best,

R. Lebrón

Comment: Duplicate of this question?: https://askubuntu.com/questions/384758/name-of-detect-keyboard-layout-tool